# populate one dropdown list from another in jquery easyui

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I have one combogrid in jquery easyui which lists department.

I want another combogrid which is populated on selecting the data selected from the first combogrid.

How can I do this?

Comment: and i want to close this question for not giving enough info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share your code? What have you tried?

Comment: You could ask this in http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php

Comment: where is your data coming from ? purely front end or a backend php/servlet ?